# Open URL in opera crypto browser

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, opera

When the user taps on a button i want to check if they have opera crypto browser installed. If they have it installed already then i want to open the url in opera crypto browser otherwise they will be redirected to app store to install the app.

The only problem with this code is that it will just open the opera crypto browser app instead of opening and loading the url that i have given. Everything else works fine. Is there anything i am doing wrong in the url or code?

```
let appScheme = "\("cryptobrowser")://app"
let appUrl = URL(string: appScheme)
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appUrl! as URL){
    guard let url = URL(string: "cryptobrowser://reizor.com/backup8march/test2.php?token=10000000000000000000") else {return}
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}else{
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/pk/app/opera-crypto-browser/id1604311726") else {return}
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Comment: @Larme in my if condition i check if the user can open the url this condition will go in false if the user does not have the browser installed but if they do have installed it will open the browser because of the "cryptobrowser" word i have used instead of "https" in my if conditions and it does not open the regular browser it opens the cryptobrowser as intended but the problem is it wont load the URl i have given it just opens the app

Comment: You edited your question fixing the URL in the if test while I was commenting. So I'll delete my comment as it's irrelevant now. You need to check if there are open URL Scheme accepted by that browser, or even hidden ones.

Comment: @Larme yeah, Sorry for that i forgot to edit it while asking question

Comment: @Larme what i don't get is that when i open the same url from the UIActivityViewController that allows user to share a url from there if i tap the cryptobrowser it opens the browser and loads the same url perfectly but when i do it this way it won't load i also can't find the URL scheme for this browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically what i was doing wrong was that in my if condition where i checked to see if user has cryptobrowser installed and then i converted my url string to URL and opened it using UIApplication.shared.open() function. My URL was wrong.

**I had to change my URL slightly from:**

```
guard let url = URL(string: "cryptobrowser://reizor.com/backup8march/test2.php?token=10000000000000000000") else {return}
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

**to:**

```
guard let url = URL(string: "cryptobrowser://open-url?url=https://reizor.com/backup8march/test2.php?token=10000000000000000000") else {return}
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

Basically adding "open-url?url=https://" after the "cryptobrowser" which is the name of browser i want the link to load in. Because apparently, to open URl in some browsers you just have to write "browserName://yourUrl" and it would open but in most case you have to include "https://" in your URL after writing the name of browser